# Setting the capability for aws cloudformation template-validate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to validate a Cloudformation template. The command I am issuing is:

```
▶ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://template.json
```

The response I am getting, however, is:

```
"CapabilitiesReason": "The following resource(s) require capabilities: 
  [AWS::IAM::Role]",
```

I can't find any way to set the capability unfortunately.

How do you set the capability?

Comment: I have the same problem.  ``--capabilities=CAPABILITY_IAM`` with ``create-stack`` cli commands makes stacks but ``validate-stack`` seems to require this capability also but there is no cli option for adding it

Comment: It's not an error. It's a notification to inform you that when you execute `create-stack` or `update-stack` that you have to specify the `CAPABILITY_IAM` capability.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `Capabilities` and `CapabilitiesReason` outputs from [`validate-template`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) are not errors. They are normal outputs listing resources requiring capabilities that will need to be specified (via `--capabilities`) when running [`create-stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) or [`update-stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html) in the future.

You can confirm that a validation succeeded without errors by checking that the [return code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html) is `0` indicating the command completed successfully.

The documentation for the [validate-template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) outputs is as follows:

> **Capabilities** -> (list)
>
> The capabilities found within the template. If your template contains IAM resources, you must specify the `CAPABILITY_IAM` or `CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM` value for this parameter when you use the `create-stack` or `update-stack` actions with your template; otherwise, those actions return an `InsufficientCapabilities` error.
>   For more information, see [Acknowledging IAM Resources in AWS CloudFormation Templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#capabilities).
>
> **CapabilitiesReason** -> (string)
>
> The list of resources that generated the values in the Capabilities response element.

Comment: Poor design. The output totally suggests that something required is amiss.

Comment: @MichaelMügge after using aws for a while I must say that alot of the AWS UI and cli is poorly designed, one just has to get used to its quirks :)