# Requires capability named IAM - ManagedPolicy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Below is the error:

```
{
    "CapabilitiesReason": "The following resource(s) require capabilities: [AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy]", 
    "Description": “Some Permission boundary”, 
    "Parameters": [], 
    "Capabilities": [
        "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
    ]
}
$
```

after running:

```
$ aws cloudformation validate-template  --template-url https://s3-sometemplate.yml
```

---

There is managed policy defined in the template

What does this error imply?

Comment: **See Also**: [Setting the capability for aws cloudformation template-validate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38474285/1366033)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an error. This is normal output listing resources requiring capabilities that will need to be specified (via --capabilities) when running create-stack or update-stack in the future.

You can confirm that a validation succeeded without errors by checking that the return code is 0 indicating the command completed successfully.

The documentation for the [validate-template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) outputs is as follows:

Capabilities -> (list)

The capabilities found within the template. If your template contains IAM resources, you must specify the CAPABILITY_IAM or CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM value for this parameter when you use the create-stack or update-stack actions with your template; otherwise, those actions return an InsufficientCapabilities error. For more information, see [Acknowledging IAM Resources in AWS CloudFormation Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#capabilities).

CapabilitiesReason -> (string)

The list of resources that generated the values in the Capabilities response element.

Comment: Same page, but updated section link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#using-iam-capabilities